# C++ Modifying self via Passed Reference

Tags: c++, object, reference, self, mutable

A best practice question of sorts, I suppose.

In C++, I have a wrapper class for a file system path similar to Python's os.path.  In this wrapper class, there is a member function called "Split" which searches for the last occurring path separator and splits it into the "tail" (the last part of the path) and the "head" (everything else).  As it currently stands, the function uses its own member variable m_filepath for the split.

Some code:

```
class FilePath {
    public:
        void Split(FilePath& head, FilePath& tail) const
        {
            FilePath h;
            FilePath t;
            //initialize h, t with portions of m_filepath...
            head = h;
            tail = t;
        }
    private:
        std::string m_filepath;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FilePath some_path_1("/");
    FilePath some_path_2("/home/");
    some_path_1.Split(some_path_1, some_path_2);
    return 0;
}
```

When I do something like this, some_path_1's m_filepath would be overwritten by whatever "head" turned out to be.  The const operator doesn't seem to mind, either.

My question is, what's the best way to handle this?  Throw an exception?  Allow an overwrite of the object (this worries me, and sounds unsafe) and tell developers to be cautious?  Make clever use of the return statement?

Comment: I don't think you need to do anything; if someone writes `some_path_1.Split(some_path_1, some_path_2);` then you can presume they are aware that they are overwriting the old contents of `some_path_1`.  In path manipulation it's not uncommon to do this sort of thing - extract part of a path in-place, saves having to make another variable.

Comment: Just return a pair of new paths. There is nothing particularly clever in it. Ditch the output arguments. A function returns its result.

Answer (score 1):

The big problem with writing the code this way is the temptation to clean the code up so that split looks like this:

```
void Split(FilePath & h, FilePath & t) {
  h.m_filepath = getHead(m_filepath);
  t.m_filepath = getTail(m_filepath);
}
```

But since `h.m_filepath = ...` is actually changing `this.m_filepath` the second call doesn't do what is expected. (Note that your code is currently fine though - but is fragile).

The root of the (potential) problem is a combination of using references as return values, and needing multiple return values. But C++11 supports multiple return values via `tie`.

So I'd implement this as

```
class FilePath {
    public:
        std::pair<FilePath,FilePath> Split() const
        {
            FilePath h;
            FilePath t;
            //initialize h, t with portions of m_filepath...
            head = h;
            tail = t;
            return std::make_pair(h,t);
        }
    private:
        std::string m_filepath;
};
```

Then the usage would look like this:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    FilePath some_path_1("/");
    FilePath some_path_2("/home/");
    std::tie(some_path_1, some_path_2) = some_path_1.Split();
    return 0;
}
```

And its pretty clear that `some_path_1` and `some_path_2` will get their values updated, and you don't need to worry that writes to the arguments will change this, as there are no arguments anymore.

Comment: This may be the answer I am looking for.  I wasn't aware C++11 allowed for multiple return values.  C++11 is what I've been using (although this is a personal project, so I am willing to update to 14 once I know a little more about it).

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** Ah! I just realised what you wanted `Split()` to do: split `this` into `head` and `tail` - and hope that they don't pass `this` into either `head` nor `tail`.

In another scenario, `operator =(Class &rhs)` best practice is to first compare `&rhs` against `this` to avoid that exact problem - but I don't think you've got that problem anyway. In the usage you gave, not only is it clear what is going to happen, your implementation is good enough to let it happen. I wouldn't worry (just as @M.M said).

---

When you've got a member function, the expectation is that the function will operate on the instance of the class: that is, `Split()` itself off, or give up some information about itself.

What you want is a `static` member function: a function that, while associated with its class, doesn't operate on an assumed `this`. Make the `Split()` function `static`:

```
static void Split(...); // Note no concept of const required - no `this` to modify!
```

and call it like so:

```
FilePath::Split(some_path_1, some_path_2);
```

---

Or, you can make it so that `Split()` returns the tail, and modifies itself to be just the head:

```
FilePath Split();
```

But in that case, it's a little vague in which direction the split is happening. How about:

```
FilePath SplitHead();

FilePath SplitTail();
```

Those last two could be implemented in terms of the `static` method above, like so:

```
FilePath FilePath::SplitHead() {
    FilePath head = *this;
    Split(head, *this);
    return head;
} // FilePath::SplitHead()

FilePath FilePath::SplitTail() {
    FilePath tail;
    Split(*this, tail);
    return tail;
} // FilePath::SplitTail()
```

Comment: In regards to your first answer, I am not currently keeping member variable m_filepath static, it is unique to the FilePath instance and initialized with whatever is sent in with the constructor.  Split uses m_filepath to do its splitting, and storing the result in head and tail.  Wouldn't making the member function static necessitate a change to that design?

Apologies if I was vague with my initial question, I've updated just in case.

Comment: I didn't suggest that you make `m_filepath` static - I appreciate that it should be a per-instance member of `FilePath`. I suggested making the `Split()` function `static`. That means, as I described, that the function itself is not tied to any particular instance - and yet is still associated with `FilePath` operations (and can have access to `private` members thereof)

Comment: I interpret the question as saying that `this->m_filepath` is used in the `Split` function, so it does need to be a member